# Chadwick Boseman never yielded (RIP Black Panther)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

> [Chadwick Boseman, "Black Panther" star, has died at 43](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/chadwick-boseman-died-black-panther-star-dead-at-43-colon-cancer/)

Chadwick Boseman, who portrayed King T'Challa in 2018's Marvel Cinematic Universe film *Black Panther*, died today of colon cancer.

This was reported about an hour ago in a [post](https://twitter.com/chadwickboseman/status/1299530165463199747) on his [Twitter](https://twitter.com/chadwickboseman) feed,

[image: Death notice for Chadwick Boseman]

> It is with immeasurable grief that we confirm the passing of Chadwick Boseman.
>
> Chadwick was diagnosed with stage III colon cancer in 2016, and battled with it these last 4 years as it progressed to stage IV.
>
> A true fighter, Chadwick persevered through it all, and brought you so many of the films you have come to love so much. From Marshall to Da 5 Bloods, August Wilson's Ma Rainey's Black Bottom and several more, all were filmed during and between countless surgeries and chemotherapy.
>
> It was the honor of his career to bring King T'Challa to life in Black Panther.
>
> He died in his home, with his wife and family by his side.
>
> The family thanks you for your love and prayers, and asks that you continue to respect their privacy during this difficult time.

Comment: There's never a right age to die, but 43 is very young. That must be terrible for his family, and for him to have made a film while he was dying must have taken a lot.

Comment: Also, in MCU terms, I expect Shuri will take over the mantle, right? Was the second one already filmed?

Comment: In development as of 2019 scheduled for 2022 release so filming probably would not have started even without COVID-19

Comment: 2020 can please go DIAFF.

Comment: I'm thinking Lupita may take it over. They could write in that she and T'Challa were married, thus making her Queen of Wakanda and possibly eligible for the Panther mantle

Comment: "never yielded"? What's that supposed to mean? Sounds a bit insulting to him.

Comment: @FabianRöling it's from the film.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Wakanda Forever!

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## He has entered the Ancestral Plane

[image]

Hi real life activism was just as inspiring as his on-screen role as the Black Panther

Long live the King.